# How to check for empty string in ksh

Tags: ksh

I am writing a simple ksh script. I have to check if a string is empty or not. How to do so? This is what I have :

```
findRes=`find . -name believe | xargs grep -q "ser"`
if [ "${findRes:-unset}" != "unset" ];then

     print "${file}"
fi
```

Comment: I feel that adding an `else` should be sufficient since you made `$findRes` default value to be "unset" -- thus cannot be empty... so something like `if [ "${findRes:-unset}" != "unset" ];then print "${}" ; else print "Do something when findRes is blank" ; fi`

Answer (score 8):

empty is a string without char but defined, so in this case

```
[ -z "${MyVar}" ]
```

null is the case when your action failed, not when return empty reply
also, `grep -q` could be tested with a `[ $? -ne 0 ]` when search does not find the pattern

Answer (score 3):

if [ "$var" = "" ]; then

works too

Answer (score 1):

Use the `test` `-n` option, or the `ksh`/`bash` `[[` ... `]]` equivalent:

```
string_not_empty() { [[ -n $1 ]]; }
```

A stronger variation is to use the assertion syntax for parameter expansion:

```
var=${1:?string must not be empty} || return
```

This will raise an error and abort the current function